# How to convert PDF to image?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, convert

I have requirement of converting PDF pages to images. There is a background image with some text in my file, and when I save it as an image only the background image gets saved.

Is there any software available for the same so that complete page can be converted to an image?

Comment: Apparently it's also possible with inkscape: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15484727/32453

Comment: I don't have 10 rep to post an answer so here is another way, use MuPDF.  `mutool convert -o file.png file.pdf`

Comment: On bash: `pdftocairo file.pdf -png`

Comment: PDFBox also does it nicely. https://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: You can use https://convertpdftojpg.net which is secure and fast PDF to JPG converter

Comment: Using GIMP is a great way to do this without using the command line.

Answer (score 735, accepted):

You can use `pdftoppm` from the `poppler-utils` package to convert a PDF to a PNG:

```
pdftoppm input.pdf outputname -png
```

This will output each page in the PDF using the format `outputname-01.png`, with `01` being the index of the page.

#### Converting a single page or a range of pages of the PDF

```
pdftoppm input.pdf outputname -png -f {page} -singlefile
```

Change `{page}` to the page number. It's indexed at 1, so `-f 1` would be the first page.

If you'd like to work on a range of pages, you can also specify a number for the flag `-l` (last page), so having `-f 1 -l 30` would specify the pages from 1 to 30.

Note again that `.png` will be appended to `outputname` automatically, so there's no need to include the extension. Also, `-singlefile` removes the `-01` suffix cited above, since the output is known to have only one file.

#### Specifying the converted image's resolution

The default resolution for this command is 150 DPI. Increasing it will result in both a larger file size and more detail.

To increase the resolution of the converted PDF, add the options `-rx {resolution}` and `-ry {resolution}`. For example:

```
pdftoppm input.pdf outputname -png -rx 300 -ry 300
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Much better quality than with imagemagick or graphicsmagick!

Comment: pdftoppm is much faster than convert

Comment: with only one pdf in a folder the specific name of the pdf file is not needed: `pdftoppm -png *.pdf prefix`

Comment: This is really much better than imagemagick. Imagemagick actually changed the colors in an unexpected way in my case!

Comment: this is good!, but it's a bit easier to write `-r 300` instead of specifying the x and y resolutions independently when you want to set them to the same value.

Comment: Awesome, even though this is in the askubuntu section, I was pleased to find out it works on OS X as well!

Comment: How would we put them back into pdf? with this tool, to complete the circle.

Comment: `pdftohtml` (listed at end of `pdftoppm` manpage) worked better for my use-case; thanks for the hint :-)

Comment: Also: `pdftocairo -png page.pdf page.png`

Comment: Works fine. To obtain this software you can use `brew install poppler` on macos.

Comment: I had much more success with pdftoppm than with imagemagick.

Comment: Is there a way to force max settings aka no compression?

Comment: I made the pdf plot with python matplotlib or ROOT.  When I use pdftoppm or convert module to convert the plot into png, the result is placed at the top-right corner and it leaves a wide white space.  I solved the problem by adding `-cropbox` option.

Comment: To make it a CBZ (e.g. for reading in an ebook reader like Gnome Books) you can chain commands and use `pdftoppm myfile.pdf myfile -png && zip myfile.cbz myfile-*.png; rm myfile-*.png`. This will give a "myfile.cbz" in the same directory as "myfile.pdf" 

Comment: Or, to make it easier to do multiple PDFs, use `FILE=filename-without-extension; pdftoppm $FILE.pdf $FILE -png && zip $FILE.cbz $FILE-*.png; rm $FILE-*.png`. This will give a "filename-without-extension.cbz" in the same directory as "filename-without-extension.pdf".

Comment: `pdftoppm` works extremely well and supports a bunch of output image formats, including PPM, PNG, JPEG, TIFF. You can also specify the resolution with `-r 300` for example, as well as the JPEG compression (quality) level. See my full answer with examples here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/150100/extracting-embedded-images-from-a-pdf/1187844#1187844

Comment: I first skipped this answer, because I didn't want to install extra software - only to find out I already had `pdftoppm` installed on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Is there any way to set transparent background in png?

The background is white with `pdftoppm` and transparent with `convert`, but `convert` has problems with big pdfs even if I increase memory limit in `policy.xml`.

Comment: is there any way to add password ?

Comment: @turdus-merula Seemingly `cairo` is buggier than `ppm`.

Comment: `-cropbox` exported the pages as I expected, so try using this option if you don't like your initial results.

Comment: Sidenote: To install the software on Ubuntu: `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install poppler-utils`

Comment: If you want to resize the resulting PNG use e.g. `-scale-to 300`. This will give a PNG with max height of 300px. Parameter `-r` is "kind of how blocky it will look, and `-scale-to` is how big the overall image will be (on one side)." https://askubuntu.com/a/1179820/238253

Comment: See pdftoppm docs/manual: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-pdftoppm/

Comment: Thanks! That preserved the fonts, unlike inkscape. Afterwards I used `convert -trim` to get rid of whitespace because -cropbox didn't work for me.

Comment: Amazing solution, given that `pdftoppm` comes with the default Ubuntu 23.04!

Answer (score 365):

You can use ImageMagick for this. Note that newer versions of ImageMagick have disabled the ability to convert PDF files to images, because of security vulnerabilities that are being exploited in the wild. See [the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50170/how-to-convert-pdf-to-image/50173?noredirect=1#comment1812458_50173) for more details and for a workaround.

1. Install `imagemagick` by [clicking here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/imagemagick) or by running:

   ```
   sudo apt install imagemagick
   ```
2. Using a terminal where the PDF is located:

   - For the full document:

     ```
     convert -density 150 input.pdf -quality 90 output.png
     ```
   - For a single page:

     ```
     convert -density 150 input.pdf[666] -quality 90 output.png
     ```

Whereby:

- PNG, JPG or (virtually) any other image format can be chosen.
- `-density xxx` will set the DPI to `xxx` (common are 150 and 300).
- `-quality xxx` will set the compression to `xxx` for PNG, JPG and MIFF file formates (100 means no compression).
- `[666]` will convert only the 667th page to PNG (zero-based numbering so `[0]` is the 1st page).
- All other options (such as trimming, grayscale, etc.) can be viewed on the website of [Image Magic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php).

Comment: The answer as is does work but the resolution is very poor. Therefore not currently an answer that is useful. Maybe if convert has some parameters that can be specified this could change.

Comment: This answer is much higher quality http://askubuntu.com/a/50180/11929

Comment: You can change the density by adding the `-density 300` parameter

Comment: The image in your answer is broken. Perhaps you should update it.

Comment: So can anybody confirm that specifying density makes it "as good" as the other answers here, or not? Also as a note to followers, ImageMagick calls out to "ghostscript" to actually convert from pdf to png ex: `gs -q NOPROMPT ...-sDEVICE=pngalpha  -r150x150 -sOutputFile=/var/tmp/Yf%d -f/var/tmp/L -f/var/tmp/Fic1` and if you get `convert: no images defined output.png` it means you don't have ghostscript installed...

Comment: This worked fine for me with the `-density 300` parameter.

Comment: Using `-density 500 -quality 100` I still get much poorer image quality compared to _pdftoppm_.

Comment: And to convert back from images to pdf: `convert output-0.png output-1.png output-2.png output.pdf`. See: https://itsfoss.com/convert-multiple-images-pdf-ubuntu-1304/

Comment: I'm getting this error `convert-im6.q16: not authorized 'test.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.`

Comment: I get `convert-im6.q16: no images defined `output.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258`. I know @rogerdpack mentioned it already but I have ghostscript installed, I can use `gs`

Comment: Parsing PDF in imagemagick has been disabled - https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59778 - it can be enabled manually by editing `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml` file and removing `PDF` from `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="{PS,PS2,PS3,EPS,PDF,XPS}" />`

Comment: You might want to add `-background white -alpha off` to remove transparency.

Comment: I found GIMP produces a much higher quality conversion than imagemagick (as of the current respective versions packaged in Ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: @ElijahLynn I have changed the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't make out a pragmatic, easy to follow routine with my favorite tool "convert". I'll have to agree with @ElijahLynn and point to solution http://askubuntu.com/a/50180/11929

Comment: I got an error: "convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy \`PDF'" . I think PDF parsing doesn't work in ImageMagick any more.

Comment: @Flimm, see Jezor's comment above

Answer (score 33):

IIRC GIMP is capable of using PDFs, i.e. converting them into images. So if you want to edit the images right away - GIMP is your friend.

Comment: GIMP can indeed open PDFs, each page as one layer. Choosing "Export As" seems to save only the current layer, but you can easily delete the layer after exporting and run "Export As" again.

Comment: As of the current respective versions packaged in Ubuntu 19.04, I found GIMP produces a much higher quality conversion than imagemagick.

Answer (score 20):

The currently accepted answer does the job but results in an output which is larger in size **and** suffers from quality loss.

The method in the answer given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11841/42552) results in an output which is comparable in size to the input and doesn't suffer from quality loss.

**TLDR** -  Use `pdfimages` : `pdfimages -j input.pdf output`

Quoting the linked answer:

> It's not clear what you mean by "quality loss".  That could mean a lot
>   of different things.  Could you post some samples to illustrate? 
>   Perhaps cut the same section out of the poor quality and good quality
>   versions (as a PNG to avoid further quality loss).
>
> Perhaps you need to use `-density` to do the conversion at a higher
>   dpi:
>
> ```
> convert -density 300 file.pdf page_%04d.jpg
> ```
>
> (You can prepend `-units PixelsPerInch` or `-units
>   PixelsPerCentimeter` if necessary.  My copy defaults to ppi.)
>
> **Update:**  As you pointed out, `gscan2pdf` (the way you're using it) is just a wrapper for `pdfimages` (from [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)).  `pdfimages`
>   does not do the same thing that `convert` does when given a PDF as
>   input.
>
> `convert` takes the PDF, renders it at some resolution, and uses the
>   resulting bitmap as the source image.
>
> `pdfimages` looks through the PDF for embedded bitmap images and
>   exports each one to a file.  It simply ignores any text or vector
>   drawing commands in the PDF.
>
> As a result, if what you have is a PDF that's just a wrapper around a
>   series of bitmaps, `pdfimages` will do a much better job of extracting
>   them, because it gets you the raw data at its original size.  You
>   probably also want to use the `-j` option to `pdfimages`, because a
>   PDF can contain raw JPEG data.  By default, `pdfimages` converts
>   everything to PNM format, and converting JPEG > PPM > JPEG is a lossy
>   process.
>
> So, try
>
> ```
> pdfimages -j file.pdf page
> ```
>
> You may or may not need to follow that with a `convert` to `.jpg` step
>   (depending on what bitmap format the PDF was using).
>
> I tried this command on a PDF that I had made myself from a sequence
>   of JPEG images.  The extracted JPEGs were byte-for-byte identical to
>   the source images.  You can't get higher quality than that.

Comment: This is the incorrect solution for the OPs question if the PDF is a print-ready PDF created by something like Illustrator or Acrobat, since pdfimages extracts only the *images* from the PDF but does not flatten each entire page and export the full pages to images.

Comment: @GuyPaddock Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 12):

If your pdfs are scanned, the images are already stored as part of pdf. you will simply need to extract them with `pdfimages`:

```
pdfimages my-file.pdf prefix
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution for scanned pdfs, as with this you can, with one command, extract the original jpgs, and without further recompressions.

Comment: This is the incorrect solution for the OPs question if the PDF is a print-ready PDF created by something like Illustrator or Acrobat, since pdfimages extracts only the *images* from the PDF but does not flatten each entire page and export the full pages to images.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to convert a specific page of a PDF to a PNG, you can pipe `pdftk` to `convert` ([described above](https://askubuntu.com/a/50173/23496)) like this:

```
pdftk document.pdf cat 12 output - | convert - document-page-12.png
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use convert and specify a higher density using  `-density` option.

eg. `convert -d 300 foo.pdf bar.png`

Comment: can you explain more about what is density and what It can do?

Comment: @AgentCool It specifies the horizontal and vertical image density (in ppi).

Answer (score 3):

To get a single page from gm convert, add [N] (with N the page number starting at 0) to the PDF name, ie `gm convert foo.pdf[11] out.png` to get the 12th page from the PDF.

For `pdftoppm` use `-f N -singlefile`, where N is the page number starting at 1, ie `pdftoppm -f 12 -singlefile foo.pdf out` for the same result. It appears to always add ".png" to the output filename and there is no way to stop this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with ghostscript:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r300 -sDEVICE=png16m -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=output.png input.pdf
```

See https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Devices.htm for details

Answer (score 2):

Master PDF Editor (ver 2.2) has this option built in. Open the PDF file and then go to **File > Export to > Images**. It presents a dialog where you can define different options for the output.
Extremely useful. Hope this info helps.

Comment: Is that in the free or paid version? In my version, the option is greyed out? Does that mean I need to pay? Is there a paid version?

Comment: (In case it crashes at some point with pdf with many pages: print part of the original to pdf before extracting from the output with this tool)

Answer (score 2):

PDF Mod also allows exporting images of all or individual pages of PDF files.

- Open PDF file in PDF Mod
- Select page(s)-
- **Edit > Export image(s)**

Comment: Easy and effective metheod.

Comment: crashes with relatively large documents

Answer (score 2):

`pdftocairo file.pdf -png` (was posted by Anthony Ebert as a comment at [How to convert PDF to image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50170/how-to-convert-pdf-to-image#comment1989985_50170))

Comment: Provided by: poppler-utils_0.24.5-2ubuntu4_amd64. Docs: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pdftocairo.1.html

Answer (score 1):

For high-quality output, `mutool` does a great job if the output resolution is specified to a high value (e.g., above 250).  `mutool` comes from the `mupdf-tools` package, associated with the MuPDF viewer.  The command can also do the opposite task, converting png back to pdf.

```
mutool convert -O resolution=600 -o out-pdf.png in-pdf.pdf
```