# Thunar - Custom actions: select pdf extract pages as images

Tags: pdf, thunar, thunar-custom-actions, convert-command

I like this command to convert pdf pages to png images:

```
pdftoppm -png *.pdf prefix
```

(my source is [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/50180/47206))

I would like to add a command to Thunar custom actions that would convert the selected pdf's pages to separate images.

---

When I use the option "Open terminal here" in the folder containing the pdf, and then add the above command, it works fine.

So, what I would like is a Thunar custom action with a command that (1): opens a terminal window in that folder, AND (2): runs that command in the terminal window

If I create a custom action with the command `xfce4-terminal`, Appearance conditions: Directories, that will open the terminal in that folder.

If I replace the command with `xfce4-terminal -e "pdftoppm -png *.pdf prefix"`, nothing seems to happen. To see clearer it is useful to keep that terminal window open after the command was run, but I do not know how to do that with the Xfce terminal.

Using gnome-terminal I create a profile called `new1` with the setting "When command exits: Hold the terminal open" then add to custom action this command:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "pdftoppm -png *.pdf prefix"
```

But this gives an error;

```
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '*.pdf': No such file or directory.
```

Comment: http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions

Comment: @the_Seppi - would you care do provide an answer with the exact command and setting? i do not know how to make an analogy for that. the command `pdftoppm -png *.pdf prefix %f` does not work just like that in thunar actions, it needs to be used with a bash file maybe or something, i don't know. this depends on the program used, in this case `pdftoppm`.

Comment: @the_Seppi - question updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test this:

Converting PDF to PNGs

```
Name: To PNG
Command: pdftoppm %f -png %f.png
File pattern: *.pdf
Appears if selection contains: Image Files
```

Comment: It should be `Appears if selection contains: Other files`. Otherwise `*.pdf` clashes with `Image Files`.