# What is the difference between running a certain command in terminal and a Thunar action command that opens a terminal and runs the first command?

Tags: command-line, execute-command, thunar-custom-actions

What I mean is that on several occasions I was able to successfully run a command in a terminal window opened in a certain folder, but when using a command (run not directly from terminal, but from a Thunar custom action) to do the same - that is: open a terminal in the same folder and run the same initial command - it would not work as expected.

For example, I have a folder that contains a pdf file. I want to save the pdf pages as images.

**CASE 1:** I open a terminal in that folder and run this command: `pdftoppm -png *.pdf prefix`. The pdf pages are extracted as png files.

**CASE 2:** I try to do the same from Thunar custom actions. I create a custom action with the command `xfce4-terminal -e "pdftoppm -png *.pdf prefix"`, Appearance conditions; Directories, but that does nothing. To get more details, it is useful to keep that terminal window open after the command is run, but I do not know how to do that with the Xfce terminal. Using gnome-terminal I create a profile called new1 with the setting "When command exits: Hold the terminal open" then add to custom action this command:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "pdftoppm -png *.pdf prefix"
```

But this gives an error:

```
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '*.pdf': No such file or directory.
```

What is the difference between CASE 1 and CASE 2 which triggers the different results?

---

I have an answer to the question [Thunar - Custom actions: save selected pdf as images](https://askubuntu.com/q/547898/47206). The command that works in Thunar custom actions is `pdftoppm %f -png %f.png`.

But I am curious why a `command` works in terminal but a different command that opens the terminal and runs that `command` does not.

Comment: May be you are missing `--working-directory` which should be one that containing *.pdf (i.e open terminal here not satisfied)

Comment: %f required to selection of files visit [this](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ThunarCustomActions) can help

Comment: @Pandya : thunar action command `xfce4-terminal` will open the terminal in the folder where the action is run, and there is no error in this way. i was expecting a thunar action command like `xfce4-terminal -e <command>` to run also `<command>`in the folder where the action is run, in the same way as when running `<command>` in the terminal window opened with 'open terminal here' (which works, as tested)

Comment: @Pandya - when i get that error message I do not intend to select the file, just run the command in the specific folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, the Thunar custom actions seem to call the command with `bash` and makes the use of `xfce4-terminal` superfluous.

Try the following action instead:

```
cd %f && pdftoppm -png *.pdf prefix
```

[image]

You get the `I/O Error: Couldn't open file '*.pdf': No such file or directory.` message as your selection is now a directory and the current directory is then one level up.

So you need to first `cd` into the target before running the `pdftoppm` command.