# Unable to convert to the pdf to image

Tags: pdf, poppler

Trying to convert pdf file to image, installed poppler.
If I run commont **pdftoppm -png (input file name).pdf (output file name)** 
the result is showing as **I/O Error: Couldn't open file '(input file name).pdf': No such file or directory.**

Where I have to locate the input file? Is there any specific folder I have to save the input file?

Comment: It tells you the answer `No such file or directory` that means you have to show it exactly where the file is.

Comment: @Srikanth try to take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50170/how-to-convert-pdf-to-image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert PDF to Image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50170/how-to-convert-pdf-to-image)

Comment: Distro and its version, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have internet connection then you can use online tools like [Convert PDF to JPG](https://convertpdf2jjpg.net) which is free and secure.